# Swift HTTP POST 2D array

Tags: arrays, swift, http, post, request

The question is: in which format to send this array  to remote URL? JSON or as array?

Is it possible to send it as simple array?

What I want to do is, to send 2d array to url. The array looks like following:

```
[
   "deviceID" => "123456789"
   "answers" => array(
        1=>"a",
        2=>"b"
        ...
   )
]
```

Now a bit of code:

I have the following Dictionary:

```
var postJSON = [ids[0]:answersArray[0], ids[1]:answersArray[1], ids[2]:answersArray[2]] as Dictionary => [2: B, 1: B, 3: B]
```

Now, I want to create another Dictionary, like: `["deviceID", "123456789"]`, later concatenate these two Dictionaries onto one and JSON encode the result array.

How can I realize it?

For the POST I use:

```
var URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/en/check-answers")!
        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        var bodyData = // a JSON encode here

        request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
                {
                    (response, data, error) in
                    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just build a new dictionary using your `answers` object and the `deviceID` key/value pair:

```
let answers = ["a", "b", "c"]  // build this any way you want
let device = "123456789"

let payload = ["answers" : answers, "deviceID" : device]
let body = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(payload, options: [])

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.HTTPBody = body

// now issue request
```

That creates JSON that looks like:

```
{"answers":["a","b","c"],"deviceID":"123456789"}
```

If you want to see it as the server gets it, you could have PHP code that takes that and prints it:

```
<?
    $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $raw_post_data = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);

    $body = json_decode($raw_post_data, true);
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    print_r($body);
?>
```

It looks like:

```
Array
(
    [answers] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

    [deviceID] => 123456789
)
```

Obviously, I wouldn't generally do `print_r` or `var_dump`, but rather would build a JSON response (set `application/json` for the `Content-Type` header, use `json_encode` to build response, etc.), but I wanted to show the associative array in more of a native PHP syntax. But hopefully this illustrates the idea, nonetheless.

---

By the way, if you wanted to really represent `answers`, itself, as a dictionary, you can do that, too, e.g.:

```
let answers = ["1" : "a", "2" : "b", "3" : "c"]
```

Just notice that the keys, `1`, `2`, and `3` must be strings, not numbers (it's a constraint of JSON, not of dictionaries in Swift).

Anyway, the resulting JSON would look like

```
{"answers":{"2":"b","1":"a","3":"c"},"deviceID":"123456789"}
```

And in PHP, that would look like:

```
Array
(
    [answers] => Array
        (
            [2] => b
            [1] => a
            [3] => c
        )

    [device] => 123456789
)
```